# Modify PDF document outline while merging using iText 7

Tags: pdf, itext7

I have multiple PDF documents that I am merging into a single document. The goal is to create a brand new outline. Each of these sub-documents could have there own outline, I need to remove them and have one entry in the outline per document. If I click on the outline in the merged document, the user has to be taken to the specific page where the sub-document was inserted.

I am merging and removing the existing outline as follows:

```
InputStream intputSteam = googleDriveService.executeMediaAsInputStream(fileId);
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

PdfDocument pdfDocument1 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(bais));
PdfDocument pdfDocument2 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(intputSteam));

PdfDocument mergedDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(baos));

PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(mergedDocument);
merger.setCloseSourceDocuments(true)
        .merge(pdfDocument1, 1, pdfDocument1.getNumberOfPages())
        .merge(pdfDocument2, 1, pdfDocument2.getNumberOfPages());

mergedDocument.getCatalog().remove(PdfName.Outlines);
mergedDocument.close();
```

The merged document is uploaded to the Google Drive. Later in the execution, the merged document is loaded into memory from Google Drive and I am adding an outline as follows:

```
InputStream inputStream = driveService.files().get(fileId).executeMediaAsInputStream();

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(baos);

PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter);

PdfOutline pdfOutine = doc.getOutlines(false);
pdfOutine.addOutline("test #1").addAction(PdfAction.createGoTo(PdfExplicitDestination.createFit(5)));

doc.close();
```

**// Upload the document to Google Drive**

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("generated-doc.pdf");

InputStreamContent inputStreamContent = new InputStreamContent("application/pdf", bais);

driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, inputStreamContent)
                                        .execute();
```

In the resulting document, the outline from the sub-documents has been removed, but the new outline has not been added. Is there something wrong with the way I am adding the outline?

Comment: Could you please share more of your code? While you have provided the pivotal parts, the desired behaviour depends on how your two parts interact with each other. As an example: mergedDocument should be closed and a new PdfReader based on its output should be made on the merged output. Without sharing the parts of your code where this happens (or not), I cannot help you further

Comment: @SamuelHuylebroeck - thank you for your response. Please check the updated question.

Comment: Looks ok at first glance, will see if I can recreate the problem locally

Comment: I ran an example based on your provided code locally with the only major changes being 1. Outputting to files instead of streams and 2. using my own input documents. I could not reproduce your issue, my final output had the old outlines removed and the single new "test#1" added correctly. The description of your problem is consistent with the output of the first step though, so maybe the second part of your code is not executed at all?